Exclude most recent date when grouping by an attribute through a JOIN
I am looking to exclude the most recent date in my SQL query results. I've done some research on this subject and can only find examples where they GROUP BY an attribute in the originating table. I GROUP BY an attribute in a joined table.
These are a couple of the solutions I have tried, but I am having a hard time morphing their solution to my query because of my JOIN.

How do I exclude results with the most recent date?

SQL query for all records that are not the most recent


This is currently where I am at (pseudo query below). I assumed that I could just change IN to NOT IN and I would thereby exclude the MAX date, but that doesn't seem to be the right logic:
SELECT t2.sid
,t1.date
FROM dbo.table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN dbo.table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.num = 000
AND t2.sid IS NOT NULL
AND t2.sid NOT LIKE '%#########%'
AND t1.date NOT IN (
    SELECT MAX(t1a.date)
    FROM dbo.table1 t1a
    WHERE t1a.id = t1.id
)
GROUP BY t2.sid,t1.date

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide more info. Thanks!

Why are you using GROUP BY at all? There's no aggregation here.

I guess as an alternative to DISTINCT

I don't know that NOT IN can be used in a correlated subquery like that. Maybe? Just for illustration, NOT EXISTS is the way you'd see most often. ex. WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.table1 t1a WHERE t1.id = t1a.id GROUP BY t1a.id HAVING t1.date = max(t2.date)) In practice though I'd use RANK().

NOT IN can be used against a subquery, @Error_2646 . Though the IN is a little pointless in this example, as the subquery would return a dataset of a single column and row, so they might as well use !=.

@Error_2646: It is allowed to have a correlated subquery with [NOT] IN, but it is considered good style to use correlated subqueries with [NOT] IEXISTS and noncorrelated subqueries with [NOT] IN.

@ThomA, you are correct. Not using GROUP BY yields the same result. However, I would like to include date in my results. The only way I can think to do that is to include MAX in my SELECT statement. But of course, I want to exclude the MAX. So if there's a way to do that w/o using GROUP BY then that's great. I just need the dates grouped by t2.sid

Can't you just use Get top 1 row of each group? It's not a big jump to change = to !=.

I'm not too familiar with WITH. When I morph that solution to my purposes, I get the error, "The column 'id' was specified multiple times from 'cte'." Might you know what this means? I did my JOIN in the area where the PARTITION is defined.

I believe you can use RANK() window function for that, then you probably can remove GROUP BY / DISTINCT clause.
SELECT sid, date FROM (
SELECT t2.sid
, t1.date
, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY t1.date DESC) AS row_num
FROM dbo.table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN dbo.table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.num = 000
AND t2.sid NOT LIKE '%#########%'
) as date_ranked_by_id
WHERE date_ranked_by_id.row_num != 1


I've utilized this and I'm getting some errors at SELECT sid, date FROM and additionally at WHERE row_num != 1. The error I get is pretty ambiguous stating, "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'." even though I've got red starting at sid and date.

@Crimp Try aliasing the subquery, so ) as date_ranked_by_id WHERE date_ranked_by_id.row_num != 1

That looks to have done it! Thanks @Error_2646

@Crimp You might want ROW_NUMBER not RANK

Well, it turns out I'm having issues  RANK and ROW_NUMBER. When I initially tested this solution I was further qualifying t2.sid by a specific id. When qualified this way it will exclude the most recent date. But when I take that qualification away (grabbing ALL sid) the most recent date is included. Insight into why?

Do you need to remove the most recent date for each sid? Let's say sid = 1 has the most recent date 2024-07-01 and sid = 2 has 2024-07-02; in this case you'd like to remove both dates?

You are correct!

It's easy then :) Just add PARTITION BY clause to the RANK. RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY t2.sid ORDER BY t1.date DESC) AS row_num

You are the man! Appreciate your help!
